macro bug when building program
I try to build my program but this bug occur
    |
114 | #[derive(Accounts)]
    |          ^^^^^^^^ expected `Pubkey`, found `COption<Pubkey>`
    |
    = note: expected struct `anchor_lang::prelude::Pubkey`
                 found enum `COption<anchor_lang::prelude::Pubkey>`
    = note: this error originates in the derive macro `Accounts` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.

here is my code:
use {
    anchor_lang::prelude::*,
    anchor_spl::{
        associated_token::AssociatedToken, metadata::{
            create_metadata_accounts_v3, mpl_token_metadata::types::DataV2,
            CreateMetadataAccountsV3, Metadata,
        }, token::{mint_to, Mint, MintTo, Token, TokenAccount}
    },
};

declare_id!("8MmRm3eM4QZJKn6ysCiBBg4Et3EZyoCJGtA6mBCoNvfJ");

#[program]
pub mod create_token {

    use super::*;

    pub fn create_token_mint(
        ctx: Context<CreateTokenMint>,
        _token_decimals: u8,
        token_name: String,
        token_symbol: String,
        token_uri: String,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        msg!("Creating metadata account...");
        msg!(
            "Metadata account address: {}",
            &ctx.accounts.metadata_account.key()
        );

        // Cross Program Invocation (CPI)
        let cpi_context = CpiContext::new(
            ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.to_account_info(),
            CreateMetadataAccountsV3 {
                metadata: ctx.accounts.metadata_account.to_account_info(),
                mint: ctx.accounts.mint_account.to_account_info(),
                mint_authority: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
                update_authority: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
                payer: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
                system_program: ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
                rent: ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
            },
        );
        // Invoking the create_metadata_account_v3 instruction on the token metadata program
        create_metadata_accounts_v3(
            cpi_context,
            DataV2 {
                name: token_name,
                symbol: token_symbol,
                uri: token_uri,
                seller_fee_basis_points: 0,
                creators: None,
                collection: None,
                uses: None,
            },
            false, // Is mutable
            true,  // Update authority is signer
            None,  // Collection details
        )?;

        msg!("Token mint created successfully.");

        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn mint_token(ctx: Context<MintToken>, amount: u64) -> Result<()> {
        msg!("Minting {} tokens to the owner", amount);

        let cpi_context = CpiContext::new(
            ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
            MintTo {
                mint: ctx.accounts.mint_account.to_account_info(),
                to: ctx.accounts.associated_token_account.to_account_info(),
                authority: ctx.accounts.mint_authority.to_account_info(),
            },
        );
        // CPI to mint tokens
        mint_to(cpi_context, amount)?;

        msg!("Tokens minted successfully");
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(_token_decimals: u8)]
pub struct CreateTokenMint<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,

    /// CHECK: Validate address by deriving pda
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [b"metadata", token_metadata_program.key().as_ref(), mint_account.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        seeds::program = token_metadata_program.key(),
    )]
    pub metadata_account: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    // Create new mint account
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = payer,
        mint::decimals = _token_decimals,
        mint::authority = payer.key(),
    )]
    pub mint_account: Account<'info, Mint>,

    pub token_metadata_program: Program<'info, Metadata>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct MintToken<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub mint_account: Account<'info, Mint>,

    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = payer,
        associated_token::mint = mint_account,
        associated_token::authority = payer
    )]
    pub associated_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    #[account(mut,address = mint_account.mint_authority)]
    pub mint_authority: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    
    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}


could you also post your anchor & Solana CLI versions with also the deps in your Cargo.toml

anchor-cli 0.30.1, solana-cli 1.18.14 (src:d8e08244; feat:4215500110, client:SolanaLabs).     Also, i already try to build in solana playground. So i think environment is not the problem.

[package]
name = "create-token"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Created with Anchor"
edition = "2021"
[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]
name = "create_token"
[features]
default = []
cpi = ["no-entrypoint"]
no-entrypoint = []
no-idl = []
no-log-ix-name = []
idl-build = ["anchor-lang/idl-build","anchor-spl/idl-build"]
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = { version = "0.30.1", features = ["init-if-needed"]}
anchor-spl = { version = "0.30.1",features = ["metadata"] }

Already found the bug.
#[account(mut,address = mint_account.mint_authority)]
    pub mint_authority: UncheckedAccount<'info>

Here i mark mint_authority as UncheckAccount type but it have a condition in #account macro.
